# Why React Hooks is not firing validation onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Well, Working on React Hooks Form i was coding a form and this form validates every input field when value change, but the only one which is not working correctly is the Phone Number input. This just validates on blur and this is freaking me out. Here is te form live https://vaderetroshop.netlify.app/signup and here is the code.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Nav from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import axios from "axios";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEye, faEyeSlash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Countries_Flags from "../Assets/files json/countries_flags";
import "react-phone-number-input/style.css";

function Register() {

  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    mode: "OnChange"
  });
  const [country, SetCountry] = useState("");
  const [countriesList, SetCountriesList] = useState("");
  const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);
  const [passwordConfirmShown, setPasswordConfirmShown] = useState(false);
  const password = watch("password");
  const passwordMessage =
    <div>
      <p className="password-validate-msg-main"> Password must have: </p>
      <p className="password-validate-msg">* Minimun 8 characters</p>
      <p className="password-validate-msg">* Maximun 16 characters</p>
      <p className="password-validate-msg">* At least one uppercase</p>
      <p className="password-validate-msg">* At least one lowercase</p>
      <p className="password-validate-msg">* At least one special character</p> </div>;
  const eye = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} />
  const closeEye = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEyeSlash} />

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    SetCountry(event.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
  const togglePasswordVisiblity = () => {
    setPasswordShown(passwordShown ? false : true);
  };
  const togglePasswordConfirmVisiblity = () => {
    setPasswordConfirmShown(passwordConfirmShown ? false : true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {

  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      <div className="content-wrap">
        <Nav />
        <h1 className="title">Sign Up</h1>
        <div className="div-signup-form">
          <form className="register-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <TextField id="standard-basic"
              name="name"
              className={errors.name ? "warning-input-style warning-color-style" : null}
              label="Name"
              variant="standard" {...register("name", {
                required: "This field is required",
                minLength: { value: 3, message: "Name field must be at least 3 characters and not more than 30 characters" },
                maxLength: { value: 30, message: "Name field must be at least 3 characters and not more than 30 characters" },
                pattern: { value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/, message: "Only alphabetic characters are allowed for this field" }
              })} />
            {errors.name && <span className="form-warning-msg"> {errors.name.message} </span>}
            <TextField id="standard-basic"
              name="lastname"
              className={errors.lastnames ? "warning-input-style warning-color-style" : null}
              label="Lastname(s)"
              variant="standard" {...register("lastnames", {
                required: "This field is required",
                minLength: { value: 2, message: "Lastname field must be at least 2 characters and not more than 30 characters" },
                maxLength: { value: 30, message: "Lastname field must be at least 2 characters and not more than 30 characters" },
                pattern: { value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/, message: "Only alphabetic characters are allowed for this field" }
              })} />

            {errors.lastnames && <span className="form-warning-msg"> {errors.lastnames.message} </span>}
            <TextField
              id="standard-select-categories"
              className={errors.country ? "warning-input-style warning-color-style" : null}
              select
              label="Select Country"
              // value="j balvin"
              onChange={handleChange}
              variant="standard"
              {...register("country", { required: "This field is required" })}
            >
              {Countries_Flags.map((option, index) => (
                <MenuItem key={index} value={option.value}>
                  {<img src={"https://img.mobiscroll.com/demos/flags/" + option.value + ".png"} className="select-country-items" />}
                  {option.text}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
            {errors.country && <span className="form-warning-msg"> {errors.country.message} </span>}
            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Email" variant="standard" className={errors.email ? "warning-input-style warning-color-style" : null}
              {...register("email", {
                required: "This field is required",
                pattern: { value: /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i, message: "Invalid email address" }
              })} />
            {errors.email && <span className="form-warning-msg"> {errors.email.message} </span>}
            <div></div>
            <PhoneInput
              initialValueFormat="national"
              className={errors.phonenumber ? "warning-input-style warning-color-style" : null}
              placeholder="Enter phone number"
              {...register("phonenumber", { required: "This field is required", pattern: {value: /(\+\d{1,3}\s?)?((\(\d{3}\)\s?)|(\d{3})(\s|-?))(\d{3}(\s|-?))(\d{4})(\s?(([E|e]xt[:|.|]?)|x|X)(\s?\d+))?/g, message: "Invalid phone number" } })}
            />
            {errors.phonenumber && <span className="form-warning-msg"> {errors.phonenumber.message} </span>}
            <div className="input-password">
              <TextField id="standard-basic" type={!passwordShown ? "password" : "text"}
                className={errors.password ? "warning-input-style warning-color-style" : null}
                label="Password" variant="standard"
                {...register("password", {
                  required: "This field is required", minLength: { value: 8, message: passwordMessage }, maxLength: { value: 16, message: passwordMessage },
                  pattern: { value: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,16})/gm, message: passwordMessage }
                })}
              />
              <div className="icon-eye">
                <i onClick={togglePasswordVisiblity} className="icon"> {passwordShown ? eye : closeEye} </i>
              </div>
            </div>
            {errors.password && <span className="form-warning-msg"> {errors.password.message} </span>}
            <div className="input-password">
              <TextField id="standard-basic" type={!passwordConfirmShown ? "password" : "text"}
                className={errors.confirmPassword ? "warning-input-style warning-color-style" : null}
                {...register("confirmPassword", { required: "This field is required", validate: (value) => value === password || "Confirm password must match with password field" })}
                label="Confirm password" variant="standard" />
              <div className="icon-eye">
                <i onClick={togglePasswordConfirmVisiblity} className="icon"> {passwordConfirmShown ? eye : closeEye} </i>
              </div>
            </div>
            {errors.confirmPassword && <span className="form-warning-msg"> {errors.confirmPassword.message} </span>}
            <button className="button-signup" type="submit">
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: can you add this to a sandbox

Comment: @DharmikPatel Yes, of course my friend. https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-heisenberg-ojp9gd?file=/src/components/Register.js:5714-5748 PD: add this to CSB url  https://ojp9gd.csb.app/signup PD2: Idk why CSB debugged my App with errors.